# Wifi Adapter not found for Dell Inspiron 5590, Processor is i5 10th gen 10210U. Wireless Card is Intel Wireless AC 9462

Tags: wireless, dell, intel

I have run the following script but all in vain....

```
sudo apt install git dkms
git clone -b extended --single-branch https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git
sudo dkms add rtlwifi_new
sudo dkms install rtlwifi-new/0.6
sudo apt update
sudo apt install build-essential dkms git
git clone https://github.com/jeremyb31/rtl8723de.git
sudo dkms add ./rtl8723de
sudo dkms build rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414
sudo dkms install rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414
```

If you get an error then:

```
sudo apt-get install dkms git build-essential
git clone -b extended https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git
sudo dkms add ./rtlwifi_new
sudo dkms install rtlwifi-new/0.6
sudo cp -r rtlwifi_new/firmware/rtlwifi/ /lib/firmware/rtlwifi/
echo "options rtl8723de ant_sel=2" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723de.conf
echo "options rtl8723be ant_sel=2" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf
```

Reboot

Should work

Here's the output asked by @pilot6

```
$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list
00:14.3 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:02f0]
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:42a4]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

The solution linked by @pilot6 has initial condition different from that of mine, so please help.

I am adding certain other results that I think might be useful...

```
$ lspci -nn | grep -i network
00:14.3 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:02f0]

$ uname -r
5.0.0-36-generic
kratik@advo-kratik:~$ iwconfig
bnep0     no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

$ sudo lshw -C network
  *-network                 
       description: Network controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 14.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=iwlwifi latency=0
       resources: irq:16 memory:c2218000-c221bfff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 3
       logical name: bnep0
       serial: 50:e0:85:24:3d:cf
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes ip=192.168.44.21 multicast=yes

$ dmesg | grep -i firm
[    0.169085] ACPI: [Firmware Bug]: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[    2.223064] Bluetooth: hci0: Minimum firmware build 1 week 10 2014
[    2.228473] Bluetooth: hci0: Found device firmware: intel/ibt-19-0-0.sfi
[    2.246370] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: loaded firmware version 43.95eb4e97.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    2.334734] [drm] Finished loading DMC firmware i915/kbl_dmc_ver1_04.bin (v1.4)
[    2.558839] [Firmware Bug]: ACPI(PXSX) defines _DOD but not _DOS
[    3.755538] Bluetooth: hci0: Waiting for firmware download to complete
[    3.756051] Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware loaded in 1500660 usecs
[    7.483035] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to load firmware chunk!

$ sudo dpkg -s linux-firmware | grep Ver
Version: 1.173.12
```

I have run all the commands suggested by @chili555 in the answer and have rebooted the system. Here is the output asked for by @chili555 :

```
$ dmesg | grep iwl
[    2.197421] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    2.202477] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-jf-b0-50.ucode failed with error -2
[    2.202491] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-jf-b0-49.ucode failed with error -2
[    2.211472] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: loaded firmware version 48.4fa0041f.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    2.235138] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 9462, REV=0x354
[    2.365426] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: base HW address: 50:e0:85:24:3d:cb
[    2.425467] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3 wlp0s20f3: renamed from wlan0
[    4.632539] Modules linked in: snd_soc_hdac_hdmi snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic cmac bnep snd_soc_dmic sof_pci_dev snd_sof_intel_hda_common snd_sof_intel_hda arc4 snd_sof_xtensa_dsp snd_sof snd_soc_hdac_hda snd_hda_ext_core snd_soc_acpi_intel_match nls_iso8859_1 snd_soc_acpi dell_laptop(+) intel_rapl snd_soc_core ledtrig_audio x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp dell_smm_hwmon coretemp snd_compress ac97_bus snd_pcm_dmaengine kvm_intel snd_hda_intel snd_intel_nhlt snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core crct10dif_pclmul snd_hwdep crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel i915 snd_pcm snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event iwlmvm snd_rawmidi nouveau(+) aesni_intel mac80211 kvmgt vfio_mdev aes_x86_64 mdev crypto_simd cryptd vfio_iommu_type1 snd_seq vfio glue_helper dell_wmi kvm intel_cstate dell_smbios intel_rapl_perf input_leds mxm_wmi idma64 dcdbas virt_dma serio_raw uvcvideo ttm irqbypass snd_seq_device iwlwifi videobuf2_vmalloc snd_timer intel_wmi_thunderbolt drm_kms_helper btusb btrtl wmi_bmof
[   14.845071] Modules linked in: joydev hid_multitouch snd_soc_hdac_hdmi snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic cmac bnep snd_soc_dmic sof_pci_dev snd_sof_intel_hda_common snd_sof_intel_hda arc4 snd_sof_xtensa_dsp snd_sof snd_soc_hdac_hda snd_hda_ext_core snd_soc_acpi_intel_match nls_iso8859_1 snd_soc_acpi dell_laptop intel_rapl snd_soc_core ledtrig_audio x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp dell_smm_hwmon coretemp snd_compress ac97_bus snd_pcm_dmaengine kvm_intel snd_hda_intel snd_intel_nhlt snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core crct10dif_pclmul snd_hwdep crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel i915 snd_pcm snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event iwlmvm snd_rawmidi nouveau aesni_intel mac80211 kvmgt vfio_mdev aes_x86_64 mdev crypto_simd cryptd vfio_iommu_type1 snd_seq vfio glue_helper dell_wmi kvm intel_cstate dell_smbios intel_rapl_perf input_leds mxm_wmi idma64 dcdbas virt_dma serio_raw uvcvideo ttm irqbypass snd_seq_device iwlwifi videobuf2_vmalloc snd_timer intel_wmi_thunderbolt drm_kms_helper btusb btrtl
[   17.020167] Modules linked in: joydev hid_multitouch snd_soc_hdac_hdmi snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic cmac bnep snd_soc_dmic sof_pci_dev snd_sof_intel_hda_common snd_sof_intel_hda arc4 snd_sof_xtensa_dsp snd_sof snd_soc_hdac_hda snd_hda_ext_core snd_soc_acpi_intel_match nls_iso8859_1 snd_soc_acpi dell_laptop intel_rapl snd_soc_core ledtrig_audio x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp dell_smm_hwmon coretemp snd_compress ac97_bus snd_pcm_dmaengine kvm_intel snd_hda_intel snd_intel_nhlt snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core crct10dif_pclmul snd_hwdep crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel i915 snd_pcm snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event iwlmvm snd_rawmidi nouveau aesni_intel mac80211 kvmgt vfio_mdev aes_x86_64 mdev crypto_simd cryptd vfio_iommu_type1 snd_seq vfio glue_helper dell_wmi kvm intel_cstate dell_smbios intel_rapl_perf input_leds mxm_wmi idma64 dcdbas virt_dma serio_raw uvcvideo ttm irqbypass snd_seq_device iwlwifi videobuf2_vmalloc snd_timer intel_wmi_thunderbolt drm_kms_helper btusb btrtl
[   19.021963] Modules linked in: joydev hid_multitouch snd_soc_hdac_hdmi snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic cmac bnep snd_soc_dmic sof_pci_dev snd_sof_intel_hda_common snd_sof_intel_hda arc4 snd_sof_xtensa_dsp snd_sof snd_soc_hdac_hda snd_hda_ext_core snd_soc_acpi_intel_match nls_iso8859_1 snd_soc_acpi dell_laptop intel_rapl snd_soc_core ledtrig_audio x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp dell_smm_hwmon coretemp snd_compress ac97_bus snd_pcm_dmaengine kvm_intel snd_hda_intel snd_intel_nhlt snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core crct10dif_pclmul snd_hwdep crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel i915 snd_pcm snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event iwlmvm snd_rawmidi nouveau aesni_intel mac80211 kvmgt vfio_mdev aes_x86_64 mdev crypto_simd cryptd vfio_iommu_type1 snd_seq vfio glue_helper dell_wmi kvm intel_cstate dell_smbios intel_rapl_perf input_leds mxm_wmi idma64 dcdbas virt_dma serio_raw uvcvideo ttm irqbypass snd_seq_device iwlwifi videobuf2_vmalloc snd_timer intel_wmi_thunderbolt drm_kms_helper btusb btrtl
[   21.023711] Modules linked in: joydev hid_multitouch snd_soc_hdac_hdmi snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic cmac bnep snd_soc_dmic sof_pci_dev snd_sof_intel_hda_common snd_sof_intel_hda arc4 snd_sof_xtensa_dsp snd_sof snd_soc_hdac_hda snd_hda_ext_core snd_soc_acpi_intel_match nls_iso8859_1 snd_soc_acpi dell_laptop intel_rapl snd_soc_core ledtrig_audio x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp dell_smm_hwmon coretemp snd_compress ac97_bus snd_pcm_dmaengine kvm_intel snd_hda_intel snd_intel_nhlt snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core crct10dif_pclmul snd_hwdep crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel i915 snd_pcm snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event iwlmvm snd_rawmidi nouveau aesni_intel mac80211 kvmgt vfio_mdev aes_x86_64 mdev crypto_simd cryptd vfio_iommu_type1 snd_seq vfio glue_helper dell_wmi kvm intel_cstate dell_smbios intel_rapl_perf input_leds mxm_wmi idma64 dcdbas virt_dma serio_raw uvcvideo ttm irqbypass snd_seq_device iwlwifi videobuf2_vmalloc snd_timer intel_wmi_thunderbolt drm_kms_helper btusb btrtl
[   23.025545] Modules linked in: joydev hid_multitouch snd_soc_hdac_hdmi snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic cmac bnep snd_soc_dmic sof_pci_dev snd_sof_intel_hda_common snd_sof_intel_hda arc4 snd_sof_xtensa_dsp snd_sof snd_soc_hdac_hda snd_hda_ext_core snd_soc_acpi_intel_match nls_iso8859_1 snd_soc_acpi dell_laptop intel_rapl snd_soc_core ledtrig_audio x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp dell_smm_hwmon coretemp snd_compress ac97_bus snd_pcm_dmaengine kvm_intel snd_hda_intel snd_intel_nhlt snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core crct10dif_pclmul snd_hwdep crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel i915 snd_pcm snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event iwlmvm snd_rawmidi nouveau aesni_intel mac80211 kvmgt vfio_mdev aes_x86_64 mdev crypto_simd cryptd vfio_iommu_type1 snd_seq vfio glue_helper dell_wmi kvm intel_cstate dell_smbios intel_rapl_perf input_leds mxm_wmi idma64 dcdbas virt_dma serio_raw uvcvideo ttm irqbypass snd_seq_device iwlwifi videobuf2_vmalloc snd_timer intel_wmi_thunderbolt drm_kms_helper btusb btrtl
[   25.027280] Modules linked in: joydev hid_multitouch snd_soc_hdac_hdmi snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic cmac bnep snd_soc_dmic sof_pci_dev snd_sof_intel_hda_common snd_sof_intel_hda arc4 snd_sof_xtensa_dsp snd_sof snd_soc_hdac_hda snd_hda_ext_core snd_soc_acpi_intel_match nls_iso8859_1 snd_soc_acpi dell_laptop intel_rapl snd_soc_core ledtrig_audio x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp dell_smm_hwmon coretemp snd_compress ac97_bus snd_pcm_dmaengine kvm_intel snd_hda_intel snd_intel_nhlt snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core crct10dif_pclmul snd_hwdep crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel i915 snd_pcm snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event iwlmvm snd_rawmidi nouveau aesni_intel mac80211 kvmgt vfio_mdev aes_x86_64 mdev crypto_simd cryptd vfio_iommu_type1 snd_seq vfio glue_helper dell_wmi kvm intel_cstate dell_smbios intel_rapl_perf input_leds mxm_wmi idma64 dcdbas virt_dma serio_raw uvcvideo ttm irqbypass snd_seq_device iwlwifi videobuf2_vmalloc snd_timer intel_wmi_thunderbolt drm_kms_helper btusb btrtl
[   27.029005] Modules linked in: joydev hid_multitouch snd_soc_hdac_hdmi snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic cmac bnep snd_soc_dmic sof_pci_dev snd_sof_intel_hda_common snd_sof_intel_hda arc4 snd_sof_xtensa_dsp snd_sof snd_soc_hdac_hda snd_hda_ext_core snd_soc_acpi_intel_match nls_iso8859_1 snd_soc_acpi dell_laptop intel_rapl snd_soc_core ledtrig_audio x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp dell_smm_hwmon coretemp snd_compress ac97_bus snd_pcm_dmaengine kvm_intel snd_hda_intel snd_intel_nhlt snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core crct10dif_pclmul snd_hwdep crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel i915 snd_pcm snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event iwlmvm snd_rawmidi nouveau aesni_intel mac80211 kvmgt vfio_mdev aes_x86_64 mdev crypto_simd cryptd vfio_iommu_type1 snd_seq vfio glue_helper dell_wmi kvm intel_cstate dell_smbios intel_rapl_perf input_leds mxm_wmi idma64 dcdbas virt_dma serio_raw uvcvideo ttm irqbypass snd_seq_device iwlwifi videobuf2_vmalloc snd_timer intel_wmi_thunderbolt drm_kms_helper btusb btrtl
[   29.030825] Modules linked in: joydev hid_multitouch snd_soc_hdac_hdmi snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic cmac bnep snd_soc_dmic sof_pci_dev snd_sof_intel_hda_common snd_sof_intel_hda arc4 snd_sof_xtensa_dsp snd_sof snd_soc_hdac_hda snd_hda_ext_core snd_soc_acpi_intel_match nls_iso8859_1 snd_soc_acpi dell_laptop intel_rapl snd_soc_core ledtrig_audio x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp dell_smm_hwmon coretemp snd_compress ac97_bus snd_pcm_dmaengine kvm_intel snd_hda_intel snd_intel_nhlt snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core crct10dif_pclmul snd_hwdep crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel i915 snd_pcm snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event iwlmvm snd_rawmidi nouveau aesni_intel mac80211 kvmgt vfio_mdev aes_x86_64 mdev crypto_simd cryptd vfio_iommu_type1 snd_seq vfio glue_helper dell_wmi kvm intel_cstate dell_smbios intel_rapl_perf input_leds mxm_wmi idma64 dcdbas virt_dma serio_raw uvcvideo ttm irqbypass snd_seq_device iwlwifi videobuf2_vmalloc snd_timer intel_wmi_thunderbolt drm_kms_helper btusb btrtl
[   31.056269] Modules linked in: joydev hid_multitouch snd_soc_hdac_hdmi snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic cmac bnep snd_soc_dmic sof_pci_dev snd_sof_intel_hda_common snd_sof_intel_hda arc4 snd_sof_xtensa_dsp snd_sof snd_soc_hdac_hda snd_hda_ext_core snd_soc_acpi_intel_match nls_iso8859_1 snd_soc_acpi dell_laptop intel_rapl snd_soc_core ledtrig_audio x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp dell_smm_hwmon coretemp snd_compress ac97_bus snd_pcm_dmaengine kvm_intel snd_hda_intel snd_intel_nhlt snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core crct10dif_pclmul snd_hwdep crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel i915 snd_pcm snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event iwlmvm snd_rawmidi nouveau aesni_intel mac80211 kvmgt vfio_mdev aes_x86_64 mdev crypto_simd cryptd vfio_iommu_type1 snd_seq vfio glue_helper dell_wmi kvm intel_cstate dell_smbios intel_rapl_perf input_leds mxm_wmi idma64 dcdbas virt_dma serio_raw uvcvideo ttm irqbypass snd_seq_device iwlwifi videobuf2_vmalloc snd_timer intel_wmi_thunderbolt drm_kms_helper btusb btrtl
[   33.058047] Modules linked in: joydev hid_multitouch snd_soc_hdac_hdmi snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic cmac bnep snd_soc_dmic sof_pci_dev snd_sof_intel_hda_common snd_sof_intel_hda arc4 snd_sof_xtensa_dsp snd_sof snd_soc_hdac_hda snd_hda_ext_core snd_soc_acpi_intel_match nls_iso8859_1 snd_soc_acpi dell_laptop intel_rapl snd_soc_core ledtrig_audio x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp dell_smm_hwmon coretemp snd_compress ac97_bus snd_pcm_dmaengine kvm_intel snd_hda_intel snd_intel_nhlt snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core crct10dif_pclmul snd_hwdep crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel i915 snd_pcm snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event iwlmvm snd_rawmidi nouveau aesni_intel mac80211 kvmgt vfio_mdev aes_x86_64 mdev crypto_simd cryptd vfio_iommu_type1 snd_seq vfio glue_helper dell_wmi kvm intel_cstate dell_smbios intel_rapl_perf input_leds mxm_wmi idma64 dcdbas virt_dma serio_raw uvcvideo ttm irqbypass snd_seq_device iwlwifi videobuf2_vmalloc snd_timer intel_wmi_thunderbolt drm_kms_helper btusb btrtl
[   35.084272] Modules linked in: joydev hid_multitouch snd_soc_hdac_hdmi snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic cmac bnep snd_soc_dmic sof_pci_dev snd_sof_intel_hda_common snd_sof_intel_hda arc4 snd_sof_xtensa_dsp snd_sof snd_soc_hdac_hda snd_hda_ext_core snd_soc_acpi_intel_match nls_iso8859_1 snd_soc_acpi dell_laptop intel_rapl snd_soc_core ledtrig_audio x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp dell_smm_hwmon coretemp snd_compress ac97_bus snd_pcm_dmaengine kvm_intel snd_hda_intel snd_intel_nhlt snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core crct10dif_pclmul snd_hwdep crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel i915 snd_pcm snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event iwlmvm snd_rawmidi nouveau aesni_intel mac80211 kvmgt vfio_mdev aes_x86_64 mdev crypto_simd cryptd vfio_iommu_type1 snd_seq vfio glue_helper dell_wmi kvm intel_cstate dell_smbios intel_rapl_perf input_leds mxm_wmi idma64 dcdbas virt_dma serio_raw uvcvideo ttm irqbypass snd_seq_device iwlwifi videobuf2_vmalloc snd_timer intel_wmi_thunderbolt drm_kms_helper btusb btrtl
[   42.420245] Modules linked in: rfcomm joydev hid_multitouch snd_soc_hdac_hdmi snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic cmac bnep snd_soc_dmic sof_pci_dev snd_sof_intel_hda_common snd_sof_intel_hda arc4 snd_sof_xtensa_dsp snd_sof snd_soc_hdac_hda snd_hda_ext_core snd_soc_acpi_intel_match nls_iso8859_1 snd_soc_acpi dell_laptop intel_rapl snd_soc_core ledtrig_audio x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp dell_smm_hwmon coretemp snd_compress ac97_bus snd_pcm_dmaengine kvm_intel snd_hda_intel snd_intel_nhlt snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core crct10dif_pclmul snd_hwdep crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel i915 snd_pcm snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event iwlmvm snd_rawmidi nouveau aesni_intel mac80211 kvmgt vfio_mdev aes_x86_64 mdev crypto_simd cryptd vfio_iommu_type1 snd_seq vfio glue_helper dell_wmi kvm intel_cstate dell_smbios intel_rapl_perf input_leds mxm_wmi idma64 dcdbas virt_dma serio_raw uvcvideo ttm irqbypass snd_seq_device iwlwifi videobuf2_vmalloc snd_timer intel_wmi_thunderbolt drm_kms_helper btusb
[   44.421874] Modules linked in: rfcomm joydev hid_multitouch snd_soc_hdac_hdmi snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic cmac bnep snd_soc_dmic sof_pci_dev snd_sof_intel_hda_common snd_sof_intel_hda arc4 snd_sof_xtensa_dsp snd_sof snd_soc_hdac_hda snd_hda_ext_core snd_soc_acpi_intel_match nls_iso8859_1 snd_soc_acpi dell_laptop intel_rapl snd_soc_core ledtrig_audio x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp dell_smm_hwmon coretemp snd_compress ac97_bus snd_pcm_dmaengine kvm_intel snd_hda_intel snd_intel_nhlt snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core crct10dif_pclmul snd_hwdep crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel i915 snd_pcm snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event iwlmvm snd_rawmidi nouveau aesni_intel mac80211 kvmgt vfio_mdev aes_x86_64 mdev crypto_simd cryptd vfio_iommu_type1 snd_seq vfio glue_helper dell_wmi kvm intel_cstate dell_smbios intel_rapl_perf input_leds mxm_wmi idma64 dcdbas virt_dma serio_raw uvcvideo ttm irqbypass snd_seq_device iwlwifi videobuf2_vmalloc snd_timer intel_wmi_thunderbolt drm_kms_helper btusb
[   46.423919] Modules linked in: rfcomm joydev hid_multitouch snd_soc_hdac_hdmi snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic cmac bnep snd_soc_dmic sof_pci_dev snd_sof_intel_hda_common snd_sof_intel_hda arc4 snd_sof_xtensa_dsp snd_sof snd_soc_hdac_hda snd_hda_ext_core snd_soc_acpi_intel_match nls_iso8859_1 snd_soc_acpi dell_laptop intel_rapl snd_soc_core ledtrig_audio x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp dell_smm_hwmon coretemp snd_compress ac97_bus snd_pcm_dmaengine kvm_intel snd_hda_intel snd_intel_nhlt snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core crct10dif_pclmul snd_hwdep crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel i915 snd_pcm snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event iwlmvm snd_rawmidi nouveau aesni_intel mac80211 kvmgt vfio_mdev aes_x86_64 mdev crypto_simd cryptd vfio_iommu_type1 snd_seq vfio glue_helper dell_wmi kvm intel_cstate dell_smbios intel_rapl_perf input_leds mxm_wmi idma64 dcdbas virt_dma serio_raw uvcvideo ttm irqbypass snd_seq_device iwlwifi videobuf2_vmalloc snd_timer intel_wmi_thunderbolt drm_kms_helper btusb
[   63.496236] Modules linked in: rfcomm joydev hid_multitouch snd_soc_hdac_hdmi snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic cmac bnep snd_soc_dmic sof_pci_dev snd_sof_intel_hda_common snd_sof_intel_hda arc4 snd_sof_xtensa_dsp snd_sof snd_soc_hdac_hda snd_hda_ext_core snd_soc_acpi_intel_match nls_iso8859_1 snd_soc_acpi dell_laptop intel_rapl snd_soc_core ledtrig_audio x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp dell_smm_hwmon coretemp snd_compress ac97_bus snd_pcm_dmaengine kvm_intel snd_hda_intel snd_intel_nhlt snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core crct10dif_pclmul snd_hwdep crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel i915 snd_pcm snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event iwlmvm snd_rawmidi nouveau aesni_intel mac80211 kvmgt vfio_mdev aes_x86_64 mdev crypto_simd cryptd vfio_iommu_type1 snd_seq vfio glue_helper dell_wmi kvm intel_cstate dell_smbios intel_rapl_perf input_leds mxm_wmi idma64 dcdbas virt_dma serio_raw uvcvideo ttm irqbypass snd_seq_device iwlwifi videobuf2_vmalloc snd_timer intel_wmi_thunderbolt drm_kms_helper btusb
[   65.816392] Modules linked in: rfcomm joydev hid_multitouch snd_soc_hdac_hdmi snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic cmac bnep snd_soc_dmic sof_pci_dev snd_sof_intel_hda_common snd_sof_intel_hda arc4 snd_sof_xtensa_dsp snd_sof snd_soc_hdac_hda snd_hda_ext_core snd_soc_acpi_intel_match nls_iso8859_1 snd_soc_acpi dell_laptop intel_rapl snd_soc_core ledtrig_audio x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp dell_smm_hwmon coretemp snd_compress ac97_bus snd_pcm_dmaengine kvm_intel snd_hda_intel snd_intel_nhlt snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core crct10dif_pclmul snd_hwdep crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel i915 snd_pcm snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event iwlmvm snd_rawmidi nouveau aesni_intel mac80211 kvmgt vfio_mdev aes_x86_64 mdev crypto_simd cryptd vfio_iommu_type1 snd_seq vfio glue_helper dell_wmi kvm intel_cstate dell_smbios intel_rapl_perf input_leds mxm_wmi idma64 dcdbas virt_dma serio_raw uvcvideo ttm irqbypass snd_seq_device iwlwifi videobuf2_vmalloc snd_timer intel_wmi_thunderbolt drm_kms_helper btusb
[   67.818162] Modules linked in: rfcomm joydev hid_multitouch snd_soc_hdac_hdmi snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic cmac bnep snd_soc_dmic sof_pci_dev snd_sof_intel_hda_common snd_sof_intel_hda arc4 snd_sof_xtensa_dsp snd_sof snd_soc_hdac_hda snd_hda_ext_core snd_soc_acpi_intel_match nls_iso8859_1 snd_soc_acpi dell_laptop intel_rapl snd_soc_core ledtrig_audio x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp dell_smm_hwmon coretemp snd_compress ac97_bus snd_pcm_dmaengine kvm_intel snd_hda_intel snd_intel_nhlt snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core crct10dif_pclmul snd_hwdep crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel i915 snd_pcm snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event iwlmvm snd_rawmidi nouveau aesni_intel mac80211 kvmgt vfio_mdev aes_x86_64 mdev crypto_simd cryptd vfio_iommu_type1 snd_seq vfio glue_helper dell_wmi kvm intel_cstate dell_smbios intel_rapl_perf input_leds mxm_wmi idma64 dcdbas virt_dma serio_raw uvcvideo ttm irqbypass snd_seq_device iwlwifi videobuf2_vmalloc snd_timer intel_wmi_thunderbolt drm_kms_helper btusb
[   69.820157] Modules linked in: rfcomm joydev hid_multitouch snd_soc_hdac_hdmi snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic cmac bnep snd_soc_dmic sof_pci_dev snd_sof_intel_hda_common snd_sof_intel_hda arc4 snd_sof_xtensa_dsp snd_sof snd_soc_hdac_hda snd_hda_ext_core snd_soc_acpi_intel_match nls_iso8859_1 snd_soc_acpi dell_laptop intel_rapl snd_soc_core ledtrig_audio x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp dell_smm_hwmon coretemp snd_compress ac97_bus snd_pcm_dmaengine kvm_intel snd_hda_intel snd_intel_nhlt snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core crct10dif_pclmul snd_hwdep crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel i915 snd_pcm snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event iwlmvm snd_rawmidi nouveau aesni_intel mac80211 kvmgt vfio_mdev aes_x86_64 mdev crypto_simd cryptd vfio_iommu_type1 snd_seq vfio glue_helper dell_wmi kvm intel_cstate dell_smbios intel_rapl_perf input_leds mxm_wmi idma64 dcdbas virt_dma serio_raw uvcvideo ttm irqbypass snd_seq_device iwlwifi videobuf2_vmalloc snd_timer intel_wmi_thunderbolt drm_kms_helper btusb
[   71.822472] Modules linked in: rfcomm joydev hid_multitouch snd_soc_hdac_hdmi snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic cmac bnep snd_soc_dmic sof_pci_dev snd_sof_intel_hda_common snd_sof_intel_hda arc4 snd_sof_xtensa_dsp snd_sof snd_soc_hdac_hda snd_hda_ext_core snd_soc_acpi_intel_match nls_iso8859_1 snd_soc_acpi dell_laptop intel_rapl snd_soc_core ledtrig_audio x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp dell_smm_hwmon coretemp snd_compress ac97_bus snd_pcm_dmaengine kvm_intel snd_hda_intel snd_intel_nhlt snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core crct10dif_pclmul snd_hwdep crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel i915 snd_pcm snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event iwlmvm snd_rawmidi nouveau aesni_intel mac80211 kvmgt vfio_mdev aes_x86_64 mdev crypto_simd cryptd vfio_iommu_type1 snd_seq vfio glue_helper dell_wmi kvm intel_cstate dell_smbios intel_rapl_perf input_leds mxm_wmi idma64 dcdbas virt_dma serio_raw uvcvideo ttm irqbypass snd_seq_device iwlwifi videobuf2_vmalloc snd_timer intel_wmi_thunderbolt drm_kms_helper btusb
[   73.832320] Modules linked in: rfcomm joydev hid_multitouch snd_soc_hdac_hdmi snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic cmac bnep snd_soc_dmic sof_pci_dev snd_sof_intel_hda_common snd_sof_intel_hda arc4 snd_sof_xtensa_dsp snd_sof snd_soc_hdac_hda snd_hda_ext_core snd_soc_acpi_intel_match nls_iso8859_1 snd_soc_acpi dell_laptop intel_rapl snd_soc_core ledtrig_audio x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp dell_smm_hwmon coretemp snd_compress ac97_bus snd_pcm_dmaengine kvm_intel snd_hda_intel snd_intel_nhlt snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core crct10dif_pclmul snd_hwdep crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel i915 snd_pcm snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event iwlmvm snd_rawmidi nouveau aesni_intel mac80211 kvmgt vfio_mdev aes_x86_64 mdev crypto_simd cryptd vfio_iommu_type1 snd_seq vfio glue_helper dell_wmi kvm intel_cstate dell_smbios intel_rapl_perf input_leds mxm_wmi idma64 dcdbas virt_dma serio_raw uvcvideo ttm irqbypass snd_seq_device iwlwifi videobuf2_vmalloc snd_timer intel_wmi_thunderbolt drm_kms_helper btusb
[   73.843667] Modules linked in: rfcomm joydev hid_multitouch snd_soc_hdac_hdmi snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic cmac bnep snd_soc_dmic sof_pci_dev snd_sof_intel_hda_common snd_sof_intel_hda arc4 snd_sof_xtensa_dsp snd_sof snd_soc_hdac_hda snd_hda_ext_core snd_soc_acpi_intel_match nls_iso8859_1 snd_soc_acpi dell_laptop intel_rapl snd_soc_core ledtrig_audio x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp dell_smm_hwmon coretemp snd_compress ac97_bus snd_pcm_dmaengine kvm_intel snd_hda_intel snd_intel_nhlt snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core crct10dif_pclmul snd_hwdep crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel i915 snd_pcm snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event iwlmvm snd_rawmidi nouveau aesni_intel mac80211 kvmgt vfio_mdev aes_x86_64 mdev crypto_simd cryptd vfio_iommu_type1 snd_seq vfio glue_helper dell_wmi kvm intel_cstate dell_smbios intel_rapl_perf input_leds mxm_wmi idma64 dcdbas virt_dma serio_raw uvcvideo ttm irqbypass snd_seq_device iwlwifi videobuf2_vmalloc snd_timer intel_wmi_thunderbolt drm_kms_helper btusb
[   73.854884] Modules linked in: rfcomm joydev hid_multitouch snd_soc_hdac_hdmi snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic cmac bnep snd_soc_dmic sof_pci_dev snd_sof_intel_hda_common snd_sof_intel_hda arc4 snd_sof_xtensa_dsp snd_sof snd_soc_hdac_hda snd_hda_ext_core snd_soc_acpi_intel_match nls_iso8859_1 snd_soc_acpi dell_laptop intel_rapl snd_soc_core ledtrig_audio x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp dell_smm_hwmon coretemp snd_compress ac97_bus snd_pcm_dmaengine kvm_intel snd_hda_intel snd_intel_nhlt snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core crct10dif_pclmul snd_hwdep crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel i915 snd_pcm snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event iwlmvm snd_rawmidi nouveau aesni_intel mac80211 kvmgt vfio_mdev aes_x86_64 mdev crypto_simd cryptd vfio_iommu_type1 snd_seq vfio glue_helper dell_wmi kvm intel_cstate dell_smbios intel_rapl_perf input_leds mxm_wmi idma64 dcdbas virt_dma serio_raw uvcvideo ttm irqbypass snd_seq_device iwlwifi videobuf2_vmalloc snd_timer intel_wmi_thunderbolt drm_kms_helper btusb
[   75.856556] Modules linked in: rfcomm joydev hid_multitouch snd_soc_hdac_hdmi snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic cmac bnep snd_soc_dmic sof_pci_dev snd_sof_intel_hda_common snd_sof_intel_hda arc4 snd_sof_xtensa_dsp snd_sof snd_soc_hdac_hda snd_hda_ext_core snd_soc_acpi_intel_match nls_iso8859_1 snd_soc_acpi dell_laptop intel_rapl snd_soc_core ledtrig_audio x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp dell_smm_hwmon coretemp snd_compress ac97_bus snd_pcm_dmaengine kvm_intel snd_hda_intel snd_intel_nhlt snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core crct10dif_pclmul snd_hwdep crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel i915 snd_pcm snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event iwlmvm snd_rawmidi nouveau aesni_intel mac80211 kvmgt vfio_mdev aes_x86_64 mdev crypto_simd cryptd vfio_iommu_type1 snd_seq vfio glue_helper dell_wmi kvm intel_cstate dell_smbios intel_rapl_perf input_leds mxm_wmi idma64 dcdbas virt_dma serio_raw uvcvideo ttm irqbypass snd_seq_device iwlwifi videobuf2_vmalloc snd_timer intel_wmi_thunderbolt drm_kms_helper btusb
```

The WiFi is working perfectly fine after carrying out the procedure suggested by chili555. The problem is fixed now.

Comment: Do you run all wireless related commands you find in the net? Some of your commands are related to Realtek adapters, some to Intel. It is crazy.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: And is it a question or a "solution"?

Comment: OMG that script given by my colleague. I just missed the point. Can you please give me the script for this specified WIfi Adapter

Comment: This is not a script but a number of random wireless related commands.

Comment: it is a question

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu, which version?

Comment: Actually I am a noobie to Ubuntu, I have installed it today only on my system.;p

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS

Comment: So provide the output I asked for. But better re-install the system, because all that crap you already installed should be removed first.

Comment: :~$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list
00:14.3 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:02f0]
 Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:42a4]
 Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
 Kernel modules: iwlwifi
0: hci0: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no

Comment: But I highly recommend to re-install first. It is too long to explain how to remove all the crap.

Comment: You demonstrably have an Intel card. Installing a Realtek driver and adding parameters for a Realtek card is useless.

Comment: @chili555 Can you please tell me if I can proceed further without paying heed to the crap done earlier. In both the cases can you please lead me a way

Comment: It is not strictly necessary to undo the Realtek stuff; however, if you'd like to do so anyway, ask a new question. I cannot post an answer to a question that's closed.

Comment: @chili555 this question has been reopened, you can answer now.... I don't mind if the realtek stuff sticks around as long as it does not potentially interfere with other stuff therein.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your wireless device is an Intel device. The Realtek driver and parameter that you installed are ineffective for an Intel device. Although the driver you installed does no good, it also does no harm. You may safely let the Realtek driver and parameters remain.

However, if you, like me, believe in good housekeeping, remove the Realtek driver:

```
sudo dkms remove rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414 --all
```

And remove the ineffective parameter:

```
sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf
```

Now, let's get the Intel working. According to this bug report referencing your exact 8086:02f0 device, the firmware file iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-jf-b0-*.ucode is also necessary. https://bugs.launchpad.net/hwe-next/+bug/1833065

It is not present in your 1.173.12 version of linux-firmware.

With a working internet connection by ethernet, tethered or any means possible, open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install linux-oem-osp1
wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/linux-firmware_1.183.2_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i linux-firmware*.deb
```

Reboot and show us:

```
dmesg | grep iwl
```

Comment: I have updated the question with the required output. I have also cleared the realtek thing.

Comment: Your wireless appears to be working perfectly now. Is that correct?

Comment: If you found my answer helpful, please accept it: https://askubuntu.com/tour

Comment: Yeah, tysm for your help, the wifi is working properly now.

Comment: The wi-fi adapter issue is back again. I just updated my Ubuntu system through the innate software updater and after that the wi-fi is just not working. Settings says no wifi card found. I tried implementing your solution once again but it didn't work out this time. It would be really great of you if you could help. @chili555

Comment: Also, most of the outputs that I had previously included are now different, a major change now being my kernel which is 5.3.0-40-generic now. @chili555

Comment: Here is the pastebin link for some relevant information: https://pastebin.com/1qU0cF9R

Comment: Please try Jeremy's answer here and report back: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1212585/wifi-stopped-working-ubuntu-19-10

Comment: The command there doesn't work on my system. I tried certain varients of the code but that didn't work either. Attaching the pastebin link for the commands run. https://pastebin.com/zLLJD2aK

Comment: well I have added the missing command onto my terminal, but then also the solution Of Jeremy doesn't seem to workout. Here's the pastebin link for terminal outputs, you may freely ignore my previous comment. https://pastebin.com/H1nkSzSD @chili555

Comment: Congratulations! It's a confimed bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/hwe-next/+bug/1833065 Please see comments #21, 22 and 26. Please reboot, select an earlier kernel than -40 at the GRUB menu and tell us if the issue remains.

Comment: Booting up the thing in Linux with 5.3.0-28-generic made the wi-fi work. Should I make this kernel default or wait for the issue to be fixed? @chili555

Comment: I suggest that you make -28 the default and add your comments to the bug report I linked.