# Wifi stopped working, Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: wireless, iwlwifi

I've installed Ubuntu on a Lenovo Yoga c740, dual booting with Windows.  This was going great for a month or so.  Everything just worked.

Today, I wanted to try out a tiled window manager.  Sounds innocent enough, right?

I installed two of them.

This:

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:kgilmer/regolith-stable
sudo apt install regolith-desktop
```

And this:

```
sudo apt install awesome
```

I tried out Regolith and loved it... only to find out later that my internet connection was broken.  One of the installations broke it, or it broke randomly.  I don't know.  I've uninstalled both `awesome` and `regolith-desktop` but that did not fix anything.

At this point, I just want to find what I broke and fix it, but I can't.  I could really use some help.

`> uname -r`

```
5.3.0-40-generic
```

The Wi-Fi Settings GUI says **"No Wi-Fi Adapter Found"**.

Makes sense.  Where did it go?

`> ip link show`

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: enp0s20f0u1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether [my mac address] brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Just to be sure:

`> iwconfig`

```
lo        no wireless extensions.
enp0s20f0u1  no wireless extensions.
```

Here's my device:

`> lspci -nn | grep -i network`

```
00:14.3 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:02f0]
```

From what I can tell, the driver is okay?

`> sudo lshw -class network`

```
  *-network
       description: Network controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 14.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=iwlwifi latency=0
       resources: irq:16 memory:b1218000-b121bfff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 3
       bus info: usb@1:1
       logical name: enp0s20f0u1
       serial: 24:41:8c:e2:62:b9
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rndis_host driverversion=22-Aug-2005 firmware=RNDIS device ip=192.168.42.138 link=yes multicast=yes
```

And it appears to be loaded (though I don't know what the second line is about):

`> lsmod | grep iwlwifi`

```
iwlwifi               348160  1 iwlmvm
cfg80211              712704  3 iwlmvm,iwlwifi,mac80211
```

Also, nothing is explicitly blocked:

`> rfkill list`

```
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
```

This looks suspicious, but I don't know what it means:

`> dmesg | grep wifi`

```
[    3.270375] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: TLV_FW_FSEQ_VERSION: FSEQ Version: 43.2.23.17
[    3.270793] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: loaded firmware version 48.4fa0041f.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    3.368773] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected Intel(R) Wireless-AC 9560, REV=0x354
[    4.376571] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Collecting data: trigger 15 fired.
[    4.376657] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[    4.376663] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Status: 0x00000000, count: -1946784483
[    4.376666] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Loaded firmware version: 48.4fa0041f.0

...

[    4.377096] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: SecBoot CPU1 Status: 0x5bfc, CPU2 Status: 0x3
[    4.377099] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to start RT ucode: -110
[    4.377105] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Firmware not running - cannot dump error
[    4.388633] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to run INIT ucode: -110
```

Do I need to do something fancy with firmware?  If so, I don't know what.

As a final piece of data: I should add that when things first broke, I wasn't able to connect to the internet via USB tethering either.  I had to switch to Windows, find my Mac address, and now I can make it work if I run this after booting:

`sudo ip link set dev enp0s20f0u1 address [my mac address]`

(I had not tried USB tethering prior to debugging this wifi issue, so I don't know for sure if this had been broken since installing.)

Currently, that janky USB connection is the only way I can get on the internet.  I would really love to have wifi back!!

Comment: Try another kernels. You are not the first person today asking about wi-fi stopped working on the kernel you mentioned.

Comment: Use Grub Advanced options menu to boot into an older kernel for now

Comment: Yes! Okay, that did work `uname -r` -> `5.3.0-29-generic`.  I would assume, then, that my issues were not related to those window managers being installed.  Would you agree?

Answer (score 1):

In terminal do

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:canonical-hwe-team/backport-iwlwifi
sudo apt update
sudo apt install backport-iwlwifi-dkms
```

Reboot, hopefully it installs for the 5.3.0-40 kernel also

Comment: This fixes the Lenovo c7450 on a fresh Xubuntu 19.10 install. Thank you.