# Lenovo Yoga C740 does not work with WiFi AFTER install of 19.10

Tags: lenovo, 19.10, iwlwifi

I recently booted and installed 19.10 on my new Lenovo Yoga C740. The Intel WiFi adapter worked perfectly fine when I was running from the live boot.

However, there was no WiFi available after I did the install and rebooted from the newly installed OS on the internal drive.

How may I troubleshoot this to get WiFi working again?

lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list; dmesg | grep iwl


00:14.3 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device
[8086:02f0]


    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:0034]


    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi


    Kernel modules: iwlwifi


0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN


    Soft blocked: no


    Hard blocked: no


1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth


    Soft blocked: yes


    Hard blocked: no


2: hci0: Bluetooth


    Soft blocked: yes


    Hard blocked: no


[    3.580003] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: TLV_FW_FSEQ_VERSION: FSEQ
Version: 43.2.23.17


[    3.580289] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: loaded firmware version
48.4fa0041f.0 op_mode iwlmvm


[    3.683901] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected Intel(R) Wireless-AC
9560, REV=0x354


[    4.696901] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Collecting data: trigger 15
fired.


[    4.696994] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Start IWL Error Log Dump:


[    4.696998] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Status: 0x00000000, count:
-367666734


[    4.697000] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Loaded firmware version:
48.4fa0041f.0


[    4.697002] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x5FF7BFD0 | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT 




[    4.697004] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x099758B5 | trm_hw_status0


[    4.697005] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x15DAD418 | trm_hw_status1


[    4.697007] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xD6EC2FEB | branchlink2


[    4.697008] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xF3F3EB2E | interruptlink1


[    4.697010] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0C0A10A1 | interruptlink2


[    4.697011] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x2A5D6F28 | data1


[    4.697013] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xFF578F7A | data2


[    4.697014] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xF4731EBD | data3


[    4.697016] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x166D8A42 | beacon time


[    4.697017] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x66F00216 | tsf low


[    4.697019] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x7EDD8D2D | tsf hi


[    4.697020] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xAB5F7BB7 | time gp1


[    4.697022] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x08F016A6 | time gp2


[    4.697023] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xB10CAC32 | uCode revision type


[    4.697024] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xB36D6AAF | uCode version major


[    4.697026] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xFC03DE7E | uCode version minor


[    4.697027] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x7BD936B5 | hw version


[    4.697029] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x19584EBD | board version


[    4.697030] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x182139F9 | hcmd


[    4.697032] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x9DE48EFE | isr0


[    4.697033] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA7799BF2 | isr1


[    4.697035] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x165BD80E | isr2


[    4.697036] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xB0A00597 | isr3


[    4.697037] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x68EA89CB | isr4


[    4.697039] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xFB1A94EB | last cmd Id


[    4.697040] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xAA858B3A | wait_event


[    4.697042] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xDD336702 | l2p_control


[    4.697043] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x31F07DEE | l2p_duration


[    4.697045] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xF1BF5F96 | l2p_mhvalid


[    4.697046] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x41053061 | l2p_addr_match


[    4.697048] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x6615008F | lmpm_pmg_sel


[    4.697049] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xDDCE6E36 | timestamp


[    4.697051] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x2DEAB302 | flow_handler


[    4.697095] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Start IWL Error Log Dump:


[    4.697097] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Status: 0x00000000, count: 7


[    4.697099] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x201013F1 | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT


[    4.697100] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | umac branchlink1


[    4.697102] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC008CF5C | umac branchlink2


[    4.697103] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | umac interruptlink1


[    4.697105] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | umac interruptlink2


[    4.697106] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000003 | umac data1


[    4.697108] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x20000302 | umac data2


[    4.697109] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01300202 | umac data3


[    4.697111] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000030 | umac major


[    4.697112] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x4FA0041F | umac minor


[    4.697114] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00005CF0 | frame pointer


[    4.697115] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC0887F58 | stack pointer


[    4.697117] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | last host cmd


[    4.697118] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr status reg


[    4.697144] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Fseq Registers:


[    4.697147] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000003 | FSEQ_ERROR_CODE


[    4.697150] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 |
FSEQ_TOP_INIT_VERSION


[    4.697154] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x37481218 |
FSEQ_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION


[    4.697157] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000A384 | FSEQ_OTP_VERSION


[    4.697160] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x004C9625 |
FSEQ_TOP_CONTENT_VERSION


[    4.697163] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x09065109 | FSEQ_ALIVE_TOKEN


[    4.697166] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x90AF1D9C | FSEQ_CNVI_ID


[    4.697169] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x2A6212BC | FSEQ_CNVR_ID


[    4.697172] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x20000302 | CNVI_AUX_MISC_CHIP


[    4.697178] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01300202 | CNVR_AUX_MISC_CHIP


[    4.697183] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000485B |
CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_DIG_DCDC_VTRIM


[    4.697235] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA5A5A5A2 |
CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_ACTIVE_VDIG_MIRROR


[    4.697265] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: SecBoot CPU1 Status: 0x5c5a,
CPU2 Status: 0x3


[    4.697267] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to start RT ucode: -110


[    4.697270] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Firmware not running - cannot
dump error

[    4.708935] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to run INIT ucode: -110

10

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list; dmesg | grep iwl` terminal command.

Comment: This answer fixed it for me: https://askubuntu.com/a/1212588/231928

Comment: Well, this worked for me. I ended up using a USB C hub that has an Ethernet port for connectivity so that I could get the files I needed from the Canonical repository. this worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this problem using the following link that was provided by Rick.
https://askubuntu.com/a/1212588/231928

I used a USB C hub that had an Ethernet port to connect to the repositories.

Thank you very much.